# Install phpMyAdmin in Centos 6

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, centos6

I am installing mysql and php on CentOS 6. While trying to install phpMyAdmin i am getting the following error on command prompt

**No package phpMyAdmin available.
Nothing to do**
I am following the below tutorial to install and configure my server. This is my first attempt to install and setup my server

[LINK](http://www.krizna.com/centos/how-install-phpmyadmin-centos-6/)

Please guide me

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

I wanted the latest version (4.0.5), not the 3.5 version in EPEL and found this information which worked perfectly for me:

```
rpm -Uvh http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
yum --enablerepo=remi install phpmyadmin
```

from http://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2012/install-phpmyadmin-on-fedora-centos-red-hat-rhel/

Answer (score 3):

Phpmyadmin isn't shipped with Centos. But there are unofficial repositories for phpmyadmin. I suggest you install the EPEL.

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-7.noarch.rpm
```

or

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

and than install using the enablerepo flag

```
yum --enabledrepo=epel install phpmyadmin
```

At the moment the phpmyadmin package in the epel repo is not the latest version (4.0.3), but it's the most recent 3.5.x version.

A small warning: don't install phpmyadmin from the RPMforge repo. Since this repo is somewhere at version 2.

It's about two months since the questions was asked, so I don't expect to be of any use to the original question author, but there are always people visiting old questions with the same problem.

Comment: The link is no longer valid

Comment: new link is :-  "http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm"

Comment: It's 'yum --enablerepo=epel install phpmyadmin' without 'd'

Answer (score 1):

To get the packages we need, we'll have to add an additional repo to our system. The EPEL repo (Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux) contains many additional packages, including the phpMyAdmin package we are looking for.

The EPEL repository can be made available to your server by installing a special package called epel-release. This will reconfigure your repository list and give you access to the EPEL packages.

To install, just type:

```
sudo yum install epel-release
```

Now that the EPEL repo is configured, you can install the phpMyAdmin package using the yum packaging system by typing:

```
sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't find it as the directions state you need to add the package (myAdmin) to your repository first, update then install with Yum. You need to search an alternate way to add to your repo , then update ya repo, then install :)

Answer (score 0):

For that you can download phpMyAdmin  from [here](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/downloads.php)

after downloading use `rpm -ivh packagename.rpm` or follow your tutorial  it wont show above error

Comment: which location i placed phpmyadmin files in server

Answer (score 0):

You can just download phpmyadmin from here:
https://www.phpmyadmin.net/

and unzip and move to apache root directory
then you can check that in your url.

Answer (score 0):

sudo yum install epel-release

```
 -some version this command not works
```

To Install Phymyadmin sometimes this command not works

so use this below command

sudo amazon-linux-extras install epel